# Dynamically creating user inputs

Tags: c#

I'm programming in C# with Windows Visual C# 2010 Express.

My goal is to create a form that shows a single row of `Textbox` inputs at initialization, but after the information has been filled out, have the program create a second row to allow for the user to enter another row of information. I also don't know the limit to how many of these rows will be needed, hence the hope to dynamically create them. I want this program to be versatile enough to create an infinite (sort of) number of `TextBoxes`/`Buttons`/`Labels`/etc.

Everything that I've seen so far is web-based (C# in ASP.Net). I want to make a program that has this functionality instead. Any thoughts or insights? I don't know if this is possible.

Comment: You could use a [`DataGridView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Use a `DataGridView` with a `TextBoxColumn` and use a `BindingSource` to attach it to a `List<string>`.